# Moving to JBoss AS7 from tomcat. mvn jboss-as:deploy does not work on my maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

We are moving from tomcat to JBoss AS7 and I been reading the docs and it tells me to do a

**mvn jboss-as:deploy** on the project but I get:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jboss-as' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/jsmith/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

can someone please tell me what I am missing in my setup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

from my pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

You could do two things.

Define the following in your `settings.xml`

```
<pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.jboss.as.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

You could run the following:

> mvn org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.Final:deploy